# Vector subscript out of range AND The application was unable to start correctly [c++]

Tags: c++, loops, vector, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm writing quite simple program in c++ using Visual Studio but i keep getting 2 errors and i could use some help.
One sometimes pops up when i run Local Windows Debugger after the app crashed and it says:
*The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)*

[message sometimes when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpIjM.png)

And the second one i guess happens between after **cin >> kwota;**. Don't really know when though, because VS is not showing any exception. It's just a message box from the os. It says:
*Debug Assertion Failed!*
*[...]*
*File: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vector"*
*Line: 1566*
*Expression: vector subscript out of range*

[message after puting second time into cin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03e5l.png)

Here you have my code. I got no idea what can cause it so any help would be great.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int wyznaczZlote(vector<int> c, int z, int k)
{
    int nowakwota, pozycja, ilosc;
    if (z > k)
        return 0;

    for (int p = k/z; p >= 0; p--)
    {
        nowakwota = k % z;
        while (nowakwota > 0)
        {
            pozycja = c.size() - 1;
            while (c[pozycja] > nowakwota && pozycja >= 0)
            {
                pozycja--;
                if (pozycja < 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (pozycja < 0)
                break;
            ilosc = nowakwota / c[pozycja];
            nowakwota = nowakwota % c[pozycja];
        }

        if (nowakwota == 0)
            return p;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int ilecyna, ilezloto, kwota, liczbazlotych;
    vector<int> cyna;
    vector<int> zloto;
    string wejscie, wejscie2;

    cin >> ilecyna;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, wejscie);

    stringstream wejscieStream(wejscie);
    int element;
    for (int i = 0; i < ilecyna; i++)
    {
        wejscieStream >> element;
        cyna.push_back(element);
    }
    sort(cyna.begin(), cyna.end());
    
    cin >> ilezloto;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, wejscie2);

    stringstream wejscieStream2(wejscie2);
    for (int i = 0; i < ilecyna; i++)
    {
        wejscieStream2 >> element;
        cyna.push_back(element);
    }
    sort(zloto.begin(), zloto.end());

    cin >> kwota;

    liczbazlotych = wyznaczZlote(cyna, zloto[0], kwota);

    cout << '\n';

    if (liczbazlotych >= 0)
        cout << liczbazlotych << '\n';
    else
        cout << "NIE" << '\n';

    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: We don't say "SOLVED" in the title; we rely on accepting answers, which you did.

Comment: thanks! didn't know if it would be enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sstatement

```
 cin >> wejscie;
```

inputs only one word as soon as a white space character is encountered.

So this for loop does not make a sense.

```
stringstream wejscieStream(wejscie);
int element;
for (int i = 0; i < ilecyna; i++)
{
    wejscieStream >> element;
    cyna.push_back(element);
}
```

Instead of using the operator `>>` in this statement

```
 cin >> wejscie;
```

it seems you need to use `std::getline` like

```
 std::getline( std::cin, wejscie );
```

But before using it you need to clear the input buffer like

```
#include <lomits>

//...

std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

Also this for loop

```
for (size_t p = k/z[0]; p >= 0; p--)
```

is an infinite for loop because the variable `p` having the unsigned integer type `size_t` never can be less than `0`.

And this while loop is suspecious

```
        while (c[pozycja] > nowakwota)
            pozycja--;
```

because there is no check whether `pozycja` becomes less than 0.

And use English word as identifiers of variables. Otherwise your code will be unreadable for the most of users.

Also it is unclear why the second parameter denotes a vector

```
vector<int> z
```

while the only one its element `z[0]` is used within the function.

Comment: thanks, im updating the code. Both problems still remain though.

Comment: @flis00 See my updated answer.

Comment: oh, right. I'm on quite low c++ level so the size_t is still weird to me beeing unsigned.

Comment: *vector subscript out of range* still remains unfortunately

Comment: @flis00 You need to test your function for preliminary supplied arguments.

Comment: yeah im sorry for the var names. This is a kinda school project so the names need to be in local language.

Comment: fixed the while loop so it does not compare negative element in vector. Also now im taking just the z to the func. *vector subscript out of range* didn't go away.

Comment: also if you could let me know what preliminary supplied arguments are I would be very grateful

Comment: @flis00 Just output within the function the passed vector and output indices used to access the vector and all will be clear.

Comment: @flis00 Within main the vector zloto is not filled. It is empty.

Comment: god thank you a lot. i copied the loop in main and forgot to change **cyna** to **zloto** before the push_back. now it all works.